# Rollupjs, jQuery and jQuery ui - jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui, rollup, rollupjs

Trying to include jquery and jquery-ui i get jQuery is not defined.

My Rollup config

```
    "external": [
        "./node_modules/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`external` means module is not included into the bundle, you should add `script` tags and load `jquery` separately.

Comment: This is to build an Angular library. I have no way to include script tags.

Comment: Theoretically you can build library which includes `jquery` and `jquery ui`, but in practice this is very wrong decision, because all consumers of your library will depend on your bundled version of jquery or even have to load two different versions of jquery. See https://nodejs.org/uk/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/